# footer not sticking to bottom viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm using the fullpage.js and on the second section scrolloverflow.js is active. for the second section I'd like a footer that sticks to the bottom of the viewport. instead of doing so, the footer stays in place while scrolling within the content of the second section as you can see in the jsfiddle. Is there a way to keep the footer locked to the bottom of the viewport of the second section only?

Thanks in advance.

snippet is not displaying accordingly, so jsfiddle which works: https://jsfiddle.net/L1fhbj36/20/

Snippet:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#FFF', '#FFF'],
        scrollOverflow: true,
      });
    });
```

```css
    body {
      background: #FFF;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    html {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    #splash {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-color: #FFF;
      background-image: url("https://thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/duck.jpg?quality=90&strip=all");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    #section0 .layer {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 4;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 43%;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    #section0 {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 3em;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: grey;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="section0">
    <div id="splash"></div>
  </div>
      <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>


    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont understund your question , you wanna keep the footer fixed on the bottom of the page ?

Comment: once you scroll the first image away, the footer should stick to the bottom on the viewport/browser window of the second section. So not to the bottom of the content which has been suggested.

Comment: you need to change your layout and use position  sticky

Comment: There is an error when running code snippet

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#fullpagejs) you were missing the `fixedElements` option.  I added that and created a working snippet.

Also, here's the updated fiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/L1fhbj36/63/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#FFF', '#FFF'],
    scrollOverflow: true,
    fixedElements: '.footer'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #FFF;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

html {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#splash {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-image: url("https://thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/duck.jpg?quality=90&strip=all");
  background-size: cover;
}

#section0 .layer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 43%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#section0 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.6/jquery.fullpage.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.6/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.6/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="section0">
    <div id="splash"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
      id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that. However now the footer is visible on the first slide also. What I'm trying to accomplish is that the footer is not visible on the first image slide, and only shows on the text section.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the fixed element outside the `fp-scrollable` one by using javacript on the `afterRender` callback.

Then use `position:absolute` for it instead of fixed and use `position:relative` for  `.fp-section` or `.section`.

Answer (score -1):

you gave your footer position attribute fixed.. try absolute instead

```css
.footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 3em;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: grey;
    }
```

Comment: position relative makes the footer stick to the end of the content, not the viewport.